# ListView showing wrong item name after filtering

Tags: java, android

I am new in android apps development. I am learning coding from YouTube. Below is my customListView code containing OnItemClick Listener and Action Bar searcView. Everything is okay but the problem is after filtering. I am not getting the right item name on Toast after filtering. it always takes data from my array source I have written in the ArrayItemlist. I know there is a similar question here but I sorry not to implement those in the same way. I have searched everywhere i can but didn't get the right way I wanted. At last, I have registered at StackOverflow and this is my first post. Please help me. Maybe the solution is about 3 or 4 lines. Please instruct me on the coding.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private ListView listView;
   ArrayList<allCountry> items=new ArrayList<>();  //item are countries
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       listView=findViewById(R.id.listViewId);


       ArrayList<allCountry> detail= new ArrayList<>();  //detail are the short description after item.

       items.add(new allCountry("Bangladesh","Is My Motherland",R.drawable.bangladesh));
       items.add(new allCountry("India","The Seven Wonder",R.drawable.india));
       items.add(new allCountry("Pakistan","The Traitor 71",R.drawable.pakistan));
       items.add(new allCountry("Afghanistha","The Ghost Cricket Team",R.drawable.afghanistan));
       items.add(new allCountry("Sri Lanka","The Mountain",R.drawable.srilanka));
       items.add(new allCountry("Bhutan","No Smoking Zone",R.drawable.bhutan));
       items.add(new allCountry("Nepal","The Buddhist",R.drawable.nepal));
       items.add(new allCountry("Maldivs","Oh! Island",R.drawable.maldives));
       items.add(new allCountry("Argentina","The Hero Maradona",R.drawable.argentina));
       items.add(new allCountry("Brazil","The Hero Pele",R.drawable.brazil));
       items.add(new allCountry("Canada","The Hero Trudo",R.drawable.canada));
       items.add(new allCountry("Mexico","The Beautiful City",R.drawable.mexico));
       items.add(new allCountry("Uganda","To be Described",R.drawable.uganda));
       listView.setAdapter(new customAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.my_list_item,items,detail));

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View countryNames, int position, long l) {
       
      // Here is the problem. it needs update position
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,items.get(position).countryNames,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


           }
       });

      }
  
     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu,menu);
       MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.SearchMenuId);
       SearchView searchView= (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();

       searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {  
           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
               return false;
           }

           @Override
           public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
               ArrayList<allCountry> result=new ArrayList<>();
               for (allCountry x: items){
                   if (x.countryNames.toLowerCase().trim().contains(newText)|| 
                        x.countryNames.toUpperCase().trim().contains(newText)){
                       result.add(x);


                   }
               }
               (  (customAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).update(result);

               return false;
           }

         });

          return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
       }

        }
```

///CustomAdapter.java

```
    public class customAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    ArrayList<allCountry>items;
    ArrayList<allCountry> detail;
    public  customAdapter (Context context, int layout, ArrayList<allCountry> items,ArrayList<allCountry> 
                            detail){
        super(context,layout);
        this.items=items;
        this.detail=detail;
    }
    public void update(ArrayList<allCountry> result){
        items=new ArrayList<>();
        items.addAll(result);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View row;
        row=convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView==null){
            row= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_list_item,parent,false);
            viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView=row.findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
            viewHolder.textView=row.findViewById(R.id.countryNamesTextViewId);
            viewHolder.textView1=row.findViewById(R.id.showDetailsTextViewId);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);

        }
        else {
            viewHolder= (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(items.get(position).flags);
        viewHolder.textView.setText(items.get(position).countryNames);
        viewHolder.textView1.setText(items.get(position).showDetails);


        return row;
      }
     }
```

///allcountry.java

```
    public class allCountry {
    String countryNames;
    String showDetails;
    int flags;

    public allCountry(String countryNames, String showDetails,int flags){

        this.countryNames=countryNames;
        this.flags=flags;
        this.showDetails=showDetails;
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to put inside getView:

```
row.setOnClickListener(.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
               Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),items.get(position).countryNames,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

and remove OnItemClickListener

Comment: Hello @Rui Alves, I have implemented that ,On my emulator after opening app same item sometimes loosing its clickable properties and showing no toast..if i click 3 time at an item it loose its properties.Same case after filtering. but, sometimes everything is okay.  it doesn't show wrong item but comes with new problem that is loosing clickable properties. i have coded it inside getview after else part before return row; like    
    viewholder.textview.setOnClickListener(new view.......)   Now what to do?

Comment: try instead of  `viewholder.textview.setOnClickListener` this `row.setOnClickListener`, in your case, because you are setting convertView to row

Comment: Thank You @Rui Alves. The second suggestion works like heaven, i have no words to explain. Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear sir, there is only one step left to complete my project. The coutrynames are fixed now showing correctly even after search. But i want to fixed the index number too (position of each item). Can it possible here?

Comment: Can you try to tell what is your goal with that? Understanding the problem can be helpful to get a good solution here. You want that position for what?

Comment: Because i want to intent every clicked item to another screen in reference of this position  . like if(position==0) else if (position==1) etc

Comment: You could for example give an ID to every country and pass it in intent...btw i dont think you want to do a if...else if to every instance, you probably are doing something wrong.

Comment: Sir, i have add those country name in MainActivity.java file. is there any way to give an Id for each. i just wanted an example.

Comment: Ok, first you need to add an field in your class **allCountry**, for example before `String countryNames;` add `Integer id;`, then change your contructor to add id aswell `public allCountry(Integer id, String countryNames, String showDetails,int flags){ this.id = id`
Now you can add an id where you are adding countries, for example `items.add(new allCountry(1, "Bangladesh","Is My Motherland",R.drawable.bangladesh));`

Comment: I have understood. I am implementing..Thanks again